# Check if user is logged in VSFTPD (from the server)

Tags: ftp, shell

I need to solve a task with a script. I moving files from a user home directory to another storage regularly (in every 5 minutes and so).

How can I detect if this user is logged in (via VSFTPd server) in which case I do not do the move?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Setting `setproctitle_enable=YES` in your `vsftpd.conf` file will toggle the display of session information in the process name:

```
ftpsecu+ 27496 27479  4 13:16 ?        00:00:00 vsftpd: 2.2.2.2: connected
username 27500 27496  0 13:16 ?        00:00:00 vsftpd: 2.2.2.2/username: IDLE
```

When set to `NO` (the default), the UID of child processes handling the connection should still be that of your connected user in your case:

```
ftpsecu+ 27525 27524  1 13:19 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/vsftpd
username 27529 27525  0 13:19 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/vsftpd
```